# What to call a script that runs other scripts?

Tags: terminology

I have a number of small scripts that are being called, in order, by one larger script. So I can run them all with just one command. I was wondering if there was a technical name for this main program (that runs the smaller ones). Currently I am calling it the 'master', but am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with computer _science_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a "driver". A program in C or C++ is a program just as much as a script is I would think. A script usually isn't compiled like the heavy-duty programs of the world like Java and C.

Comment: Note that this is distinct from a "device driver"

Comment: I'm not sure what the relevance of C, C++ and Java is. The question is asking about scripts.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the relevance of C, C++ and Java is. The question is asking about scripts.